# Check if a file is in the include path

Tags: c++, include, c-preprocessor, include-path

In C++ is it possible to check at compile time whether a file with the given name is withing the include path.

I am trying to set up a library which takes compiler settings from a user created file called for example config.h. If the file is not present, the library will default to a workable state.

I would like to do something such as this

```
#IFINCLUDED config.h
#  include config.h
#else
#    define defaultLibrarySettings
#endif
```

I guess a workaround would be to just do something like:

```
#include "config.h
#ifndef defaultLibrarySettings
#   define defaultLibrarySettings
#endif
```

However the user still needs a "config.h file somewhere in there path, or else they will get an unresolved inclusion.

A final thought would be to do something like

```
#ifdef USE_EXTERNAL_SETTINGS
#    include "config.h"
#else
#    define defaultLibrarySettings
#endif
```

This however would require the user to #define USE_EXTERNAL_SETTINGS each time they included my library.

TLDR: is there a simple way to check if a file exists in the include path such as shown in my first example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could include and fill in config.h with your default library settings and allow the user to change them. This way the user is also presented with the allowable configurations

Comment: I ended up using this method however I was trying to avoid it so that the user could use the same library in multiple projects and not have to change settings everytime they build the other project

Answer (score 0):

Since this is part of a library, you probalby have a makefile anyway, so you could handle it there with shell scripting.

Something like this:

```
 echo "#include \"config.h\"" > /tmp/tst.c
 rm 2>/dev/null /tmp/ok
 gcc -c tst.c -o tst.o 2>/dev/null && touch /tmp/ok
 if [ ! -f /tmp/ok ]; then echo "create default config here"; fi
```